# SQL Filter only some values of a field based on value of another field

Tags: sql, oracle, filter

SQL question! I want to select a number of fields in my tables and execute a filter on some value of one field based on the value of another field.
To be clearer:

```
SELECT ORDER_NUMBER, PRICE FROM ORDER_TABLE1
WHERE PRICE IN (35, 40) AND ORDER_NUMBER IS NOT NULL
```

If I do it like this then my query will **remove** on ORDER_TABLE1 all my rows WHERE PRICES = 15 (for example).

I want to filter out rows only for some values in a specific field based on the value of another field. So here, I do want to keep all values WHERE PRICES = 15 (regardless of whether ordnumber is null or not). Any guidance on how I could achieve that?
Thank you for your help.

**EDIT1:**

I know that it would work this way but I have about 10 fields to filter out the way I want it and the following way seemed not super efficient (but then, I am a beginner):

```
SELECT ORDER_NUMBER, PRICE FROM ORDER_TABLE1
WHERE (PRICE = 35 AND ORDER_NUMBER IS NOT NULL)
OR (PRICE = 40 AND ORDER_NUMBER IS NOT NULL)
--ETC...
```

Data Sample

```
**Table 1**  
ordernumber -- price-- 
-----1------------35--
----NULL----------40--
-----3------------NULL--
-----4------------50--
----NULL----------25--
----11------------60--


**Expected output**

ordernumber -- price-- 
-----1-----------35-- 
-----3----------NULL--
-----4-----------50--  
----NULL----------25--
-----11----------60--
```

NB: Dummy data

Comment: I'm not quite following - can you please show some sample data and expected output?  A side question: why are you quoting the `Price` and `Quantity` values?  Are they being stored as strings?

Comment: Hello Siyual, I just corrected. I ll add an expected output now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after your edit this seems to be close, but also returns `NULL 25`:

```
WHERE NOT (ordernumber IS NULL AND price IN (35, 40))
```

Comment: My expected result is not totally right. Let's forget about the quantity column. If I use your example, then I will not get the row 4 (Price = 50) because it filters out by price. However I do want row 4. I am trying to find a way to filter on the combination of 2 values from 2 different columns if that makes any sense? Basically, I want to filter out "where order_number is not null" ONLY when Price In (35,40).

Comment: @Aurax22: You explanation is confusing, there's no match to your example. Edit your example to show all combinations you want to return and explain why.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post. If we look at the expected output, row 1 (where price = 35) was kept because the order number is not null. However, the row where price = 40 has been removed because order number is null. All the other rows have been kept, because I want to execute my filter only on selected value in my field (here it is where price = 35, 40). Is it clearer? Not sure if that is something that can be done via SQL oracle...

Comment: That is it! It seems so simple but I could not get the logic around... Yes, it returns NULL 25, as per expectations. Thanks a lot

Comment: I edited the expected output to reflect the NULL 25 if this solution can help any other in the future. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure I'm understanding properly, you want to query everything except rows taht have their `PRICE` in (35,40,etc.) and have no `ORDER_NUMBER`?

In that case, you simply have to do something like :

```
SELECT ORDER_NUMBER, PRICE FROM ORDER_TABLE1
WHERE PRICE NOT IN (35, 40) OR ORDER_NUMBER IS NOT NULL
```

Basically, It will return everything that isn't in (35, 40, ...), as well as all rows with an ORDER_NUMBER (so the ones with 35/40/etc. that aren't null)

Comment: If my price = 35 and I do have an order number then it will not work. I was saying to dnoeth, looking at the expected output, row 1 (where price = 35) was still kept because the order number is not null.

Comment: If you price is 35, you will end up with `WHERE Flase or True`, since 35 is in the "IN" clause, but ORDER_NUMBER is not null. If you prefer @dnoeth's answer, they're both logically the same simply structured differently.